# Strange hard disc install behavior with Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb, installation

I have booted Linux mint cinnamon 64bit from usb stick - no problems very stable and works very well on my machine. I then installed to the hard disk a 1TB SATA disk suitably partitioned and experience lots of instability - freezes, crashes, screen goes all weird with lots of horizontal lines. Any body any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem. I have copied information to and from the drive and it seems to be working okay. I have checked the temperature of the CPU and GPU and all seem okay. The usb boot and the hard disc install are using the same graphics driver. I cannot seem to figure out what the problem might be. Any help?? Thanks!

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: My graphics card is a sapphire hd5450 1gb DDR3 AMD Radeon. I have assumed that since the computer works fine when booted from the usb device that the graphics are okay. The problem only seems to exist when i install to the hard disc.

Comment: Do the logs have any clues about what is going on when it has problems?

Comment: When you connect 1TB HDD only to the machine does it shows any such issues. Do you experience the same issues in bios screen?